# Add item created custom field to Solr

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

I am adding the Item created field to Solr index. This is the code

```
        public override object ComposeValue(object source, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> context)
        {
            if (context == null || source == null || !(source is CatalogItemBase entity))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return entity.DateCreated;
        }
```

I have tried `DateCreated` but this is not giving the correct value. I want to use the `_Created` Sitecore field which records the item created date. Is there any way I can read the item and get the item created date which is `_Created` field?

Answer (score 0):

The CatalogItemBase class has a field SitecoreID

```
public class CatalogItemBase : CommerceEntity
  {
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the sitecore identifier.</summary>
    /// <value>The sitecore identifier.</value>
    public string SitecoreId { get; set; }
   }
```

You can get the Sitecore item based on SitecoreID and the you can get the field value like on below code.

```
 var item=Sitecore.Factory.GetDatabase("web").GetItem(new ID(entity.SitecoreId));
 var dateCreated=item["__Created"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet should look exactly in your code

```
public override object ComposeValue(object source, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> context)
        {
            if (context == null || source == null || !(source is CatalogItemBase entity))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(entity["__Created"], "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        }
```